# How to make a function like add(num1)(num2)(num3) to continuously add numbers?

Tags: javascript

How to code a function like below?

```
add(num1)(num2)(num3)...
```

Example:

```
add(10)(10)=20

add(10)(20)(30)=60

add(10)(20)(30)(40)=100
```

How can I realize this function?

Comment: i have posted an answer check it out

Comment: I formatted the question and reworded the title for better readability. Please make sure to add what you have tried so far to the question.

Comment: Why would you want to create such a function? What is the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to create such a function. Nevertheless, I would write it as follows:

```js
alert(add(10)(10));         // 20
alert(add(10)(20)(30));     // 60
alert(add(10)(20)(30)(40)); // 100

function add(x) {
    adder.toString = adder.valueOf = result;

    return adder;

    function adder(y) {
        return add(x + y);
    }

    function result() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

How does it work?

1. When you call `add(10)` the result is `function adder(y) { return add(10 + y); }`. This allows you to chain `add` functions, accumulating the sum as you move. Hence, you can write `add(10)(20)(30)(40)`. The result is always a function.
2. However, the resulting function can be coerced to a number by the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) functions which are invoked automatically by the JavaScript interpreter whenever a primitive is expected instead of an object. Hence, you can always treat the resulting function as a number, allowing you to write expressions like `5 * add(10)(10)`.

What are the advantages?

1. In comparison to [A.J's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992986/783743) we are not making use of any mutable state. Hence, you don't need to keep resetting the counter variable `c` to zero every time you want to create a new chain. Also, you can save any intermediate value and use it later without having to worry about it changing:

   ```
   var a = add(10)(20)(30); // 60
   var b = a(40);           // 100
   alert(a);                // still 60
   ```
2. In comparison to [Darshan N Reddy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993230/783743) (which also uses mutable state) we don't need a final `.res()` method invocation at the end of the chain to get the result (although we could write `.valueOf()` at the end). Because [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) are automatically invoked by the JavaScript interpreter you can simply treat the resulting function as a number.

Hope that helps. However, I still don't see the need to write such functions. What is your actual use case?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the function:

```js
var c = 0;

var div = document.querySelector("div");

function add(value) {
    c += value;
    div.innerHTML = c;
    return add;
}

add(10)(20)(30);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Make `c = 0` every time you call the function to get correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using closure in javascript.

```
function add(x){
  return function(y){
    return x + y;
  };
}
```

In the above code first call to function returns a function which takes one param and also because of closure value of x is still available to inside function and hence it returns sum of x and y.

```
add(10)(10); //return 20
```

if you want make 3 calls real then

```
function add(x){
  return function(y){
    return function(z){
       return x+y+z; 
     };
  };
}
```

Since you want to make it work with indefinite number of calls, which you dont know in advance you can make a hack and get it working,

```
function sum(x) {

  var sum = x;    
  function func(y) {
    sum =sum+y;
    return func;
  }
  func.res = function() { return sum }   //this is the hack 
  return func;
}
```

and while adding, you can call

```
sum(45)(4)(1).res();
```